# SKLabelNode Centring After Setting Alignment Mode to Left

Tags: ios, swift, position, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have a SKLabelNode that I want positioned centre, however I have had to align the label node left and bottom to remove the well documented "jitter effect". I currently set up the scene by positioning nodes by allocating their position using the following function:

```
  func gridPointX(xPoint:CGFloat, pointY:CGFloat) -> CGPoint  {

    var xDivision:CGFloat = CGRectGetMaxX(frame)/5.0
    var yDivision:CGFloat = CGRectGetMaxY(frame)/5.0
    return CGPointMake(xPoint*xDivision, pointY*yDivision)



}
```

This works fine until I remove the "jitter effect" by using the following code:

```
   myDateLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
   myDateLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Bottom
```

I have tried to manually enter the x and y positions into the code via the following:

```
myDateLabel.position = self.gridPointX(0, pointY: 3.6)
```

However, this produces different label positions dependant on the device type. If I could work out the length of the SKLabelNode I could no doubt determine the centre, I've searched the documentation but can't get a solution. Any thoughts guys?

Comment: You cannot get the actual length of a label node. You will have to base your position by using calculations based on the device screen dimensions to make it more generic.

Comment: I suspected so, sangony, I just wondered if an easier solution was possible.

Comment: You CAN get the width of an SKLabel node after you set the text property. Use the `calculateAccumulatedFrame.width` to get the current width of the label node.